# Any reason why my Tinkercad's arduino serial plotter is not updating?

Tags: arduino, tinkercad

[image]

The arduino should be reading different values as the signal is a sine wave. Tried using different signal frequency as well as different delay(), still shows a constant value. Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending the actual reading of analog input. Your code should be something like

```
void loop(){
  int adcRead = analogRead(A2);
  Serial.println(adcRead);  
  delay(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the value of A2 while you should be reading the pin itself.

Look for [analogRead()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogread/) to start with and if you intend to use much higher frequencies and perhaps need more precise information then consider using an interrupt.